# Android background service checking url from sharedpreferences

Tags: android

I´m pretty new to Android. So far I made an App that has a webview in an activity. The webview gets the url string via sharedpreferences. 
In my MainMenu I have a button that starts a service.
This service should constantly check if the sharedpreferences url is available or not. If the desired state is reached, the app should do something else. How do I do that(checking the url)? Where do I open the sharedpref url, `onStartCommand` or `run()`?

```
public class NotifiyService extends Service {

        String savedsa;
        String response = null;
        int statuscode;
        String statuscodeS;

        final class TheThread implements Runnable{
            int serviceID;
            TheThread(int serviceID){
                this.serviceID = serviceID;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        }

        public NotifiyService() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Toast.makeText(NotifiyService.this,getResources().getString(R.string.MonStarted),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Thread Th1 = new Thread(new TheThread(startId));
            Th1.start();
            return START_STICKY;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            //super.onDestroy();
            Toast.makeText(NotifiyService.this,getResources().getString(R.string.MonStopped), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the purpose of ur service is to check the url from preferences, 
you should do it in the
 **run()** 
method which you will implement for the thread inside the service.

The business logic which you need to carry out in service must not be in main thread.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be better to check url in onStartCommand before new thread creation. After that you can pass it into constructor like 'startId'

```
new TheThread(startId, url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Bounded Service since you have to notify the activity from service when the URL is available. Unbounded Service can not communicate with the host activity. Take a look at http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/binding-to-a-service-a-tutorial.html to understand Bounded Service. You should check the URL in the run() method.

Comment: his intention is to keep on checking the states of the shared prefference, so I feel that his purpose will not be solved if he uses bound service. started service isthe currect choice if I am not having a wrong understanding of his requirement.

Comment: He has used WebView in an activity. To set the url in the webview the activity should be informed about the url status i.e., when the url is available. Can you inform the status to the activity from started service? @srv_sud

Comment: The status of the url is no longer required if the activity containing the webview is destroyed. So I think bounded service is better choice. @srv_sud

Comment: a simple localBroadcast is enough to notify the activity from started service if I am not mistaken

Comment: Yes. localBroadcast can notify the activity. But what's the problem with the bounded service?

Comment: it all depends on the the life span of the service for which he want to run.,, 
if he wants to keep on polling the state, the started is fine, 
if he want to stick to the client(activity here) life-span, then bounded service is the correct choice.

Comment: Its Patrick's call to decide which service he will use to fit his requirements, but as per my understanding of his question, his current implementation is fine and in run() method he can use his state checking business logic

Comment: He can accomplish his requirement using started service along with a localBroadcast according to you and I am also agree with that. He can also accomplish his task using bounded service without any localBroadcast. That's why I provided link for understanding bounded service. Bounded service can't be used if the service is required even after the host activity is destroyed. Here in this task I didn't find any problem with bounded service.

Comment: when both can serve the purpose, then why to spend time in changing the current implementation?? :)

Comment: Because the implementation was incomplete. There was no localBroadcast in the post. In your first comment you told that his problem will not be sloved if he uses bounded service. Is your comment correct? Aren't our arguements useless?

Comment: his has'nt told the way he wants to notify, so i dont hv any comment for it.
and yu are right, our recent comments are not of much worth. so you may delete if you feel right.
n here we conclude now not to comment more over this. :)

Comment: I want the answer of your first comment. You told 'his purpose will not be solved if he uses bound service'. Any answer?

Comment: Your answer I disagreed because of this part : "Unbounded Service can not communicate with the host activity". Can you explain??

Comment: Of course my part was correct. 'Unbounded Service can not communicate with the host activity' is absolutely correct. You have to go with localBroadcast or some other means to fulfill the purpose which can be done directly or easily via bounded service. That's why I suggested bounded service.